# How to optimize finding values in 2D array in verilog

Tags: function, optimization, system-verilog

I need to set up a function that determines if a match exists in a 2D array (index). 
My current implementation works, but is creating a large chain of LUTs due to if statements checking each element of the array.

```
function result_type index_search ( index_type index, logic[7:0] address );

     for ( int i=0; i < 8; i++ ) begin
         if ( index[i] == address ) begin
            result = i;
         end
     end
```

Is there a way to check for matches in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Not really. Checking 8 entries each 8 bit is not too bad. What you have is the content addressable memory problem which caches have. Have a look how they use a memory to check for cache hits. I don't know the exact nature of your problem but maybe you can use that solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to be done, really; at least for the code in hand. Since your code targets hardware, to optimize it think in terms of hardware, not function/verilog code.

For a general purpose implementation, without any known data patterns, you'll definitely need (a) `N` `W`-bit equality checks, plus (b) an `N:1` FPA (Fixed Priority Arbiter, aka priority encoder, aka leading zero detector) that returns the first match, assuming `N` `W`-bit inputs. Something like this:

[image]

Not much optimization to be done, but here are some possible **general-purpose** optimizations:

- Pipelining, as shown in the figure, if timing is an issue.
- Consider an alternative FPA implementation that makes use of 2's complement characteristics and may result to a more LUT-efficient implementation: `assign fpa_out = fpa_in & ((~fpa_in)+1);` (result in one-hot encoding, *not* weighted binary, as in your code)
- Sticking to one-hot encoding can come in handy and reduce some of your logic down your path, but I cannot say for sure until we see some more code.

This is what the implementation would look like:

```
logic[N-1:0] addr_eq_idx;
logic[N-1:0] result;
for (genvar i=0; i<N; i++) begin: g_eq_N
    // multiple matches may exist in this vector
    assign addr_eq_idx[i] = (address == index[i]) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

    // pipelined version:
    // always_ff @(posedge clk, negedge arstn)
    //     if (!arstn)
    //         addr_eq_idx[i] <= 1'b0;
    //     else
    //         addr_eq_idx[i] <= (address == index[i]) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
end

// result has a '1' at the position where the first match is found
assign result = addr_eq_idx & ((~addr_eq_idx) + 1);
```

Finally, try to think if your design can be **simplified** due to **known** run-time data characteristics. For example, let's say you are 100% sure that the `address` you're looking for may exist within the index 2D array in **at most one** position. If that is the case, then you do not need an FPA at all, since the first match will be the only match. In that case, `addr_eq_idx` already points to the matching index, as a one-hot vector.